# Accessing NAS drive via bridging router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, nas

I have a NAS connected to my Asus RT-N66U. I can connect to the NAS drive via the ASUS router on 192.168.1.67

However the wifi signal in my bedroom is not strong enough so I have a second Zyxel router in bridge mode which I connect to in the bedroom.  Unfortunatly I am not able to access the NAS drive (connected to the ASUS router) though the bridging router.

Can anyone help.

Thanks